# how to execute commands with env hooks depending of document part?

Tags: sectioning, hooks, lthooks

Consider test case:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{appendix}

\title{Title}\author{}\date{}

\newcommand\hooktest{this shouldn't be printed}
\AddToHook{begindocument/before}{
    \renewcommand\hooktest{hook before title}
}
\AddToHook{cmd/maketitle/after}{
    \renewcommand\hooktest{hook before ToC}
}
\AddToHook{cmd/tableofcontents/after}{
    \renewcommand\hooktest{hook before main part}
}
\AddToHook{env/appendices/begin}{
    \renewcommand\hooktest{hook before Appendices}
}


\begin{document}
\hooktest\maketitle\newpage

\hooktest\tableofcontents\newpage

\hooktest\chapter{Test1}\newpage

\begin{appendices}
\hooktest\chapter{Test2}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

There are 4 parts of document (title, ToC, main part, Appendices), for which need to run related `\renewcommand`s. Based on [lthooks](https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/latex/base/lthooks-doc.pdf) documentation got sample above using three different hook types and three different positions. Which is inconsistent <s>besides that only `env/appendices/begin` seems to be used correctlyfunny</s>.

Does `\maketitle` and `\tableofcontents` has its own internal environment, which can be reached using `env` hooks? Something like:

```
\AddToHook{env/someTitleEnvironment/begin}{
    \renewcommand\hooktest{hook before title}
}
\AddToHook{env/someTocEnvironment/begin}{
    \renewcommand\hooktest{hook before ToC}
}
\AddToHook{env/someTocEnvironment/end}{
    \renewcommand\hooktest{hook before main part}
}
```

Suggestions on alternate solutions appreciated.

Comment: You could use cmd hooks like `cmd/maketitle/before`, `cmd/maketitle/after`, and the same for `tableofcontents` to change the meaning of your command.  There are (yet) no specific hooks for your needs

Comment: I don't fully understand the question here. `\maketitle` may use an environment (often `titlepage`), but also may not, depending on the document options, but using `cmd/<cmd>/<location>` is guaranteed to deliver on your hook placement. Why do you say the `env/` hooks is the "only one being used correctly?"

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik test case above already doing what needed. but it doing the same things in different ways, which not that good. so trying to bring code to a common view. and using internal environments of `\maketitle` and `\tableofcontents`, if such exists, can help with that

Comment: @AlexShevchenko Your document seems to work for me.  I don't see where the problem is.  As Werner said, `\maketitle` may or may not use the `titlepage` environment, depending on the document settings.  For the ToC you can hook at `file/\jobname.toc/before` (I think), but I'd still use the `cmd` version.

Comment: @Werner to be precise "only one *seems* to be used correctly". @PhelypeOleinik the problem is to bring `\AddToHook{...}`s code to a common view by using `env/` hooks only. But if you both saying everything fine with test case, I hardly can argue

Comment: updated the description to better fit the problem. thank you for help